# Async await in loop stops after 370th iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, async-await

I'm trying to load a large csv file (size in GB's) in chunks. Code below:

```
lineReader.open(filename,async function(err, reader) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dataArr=[]; 
  while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    reader.nextLine(function(err, line) {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(line);
      dataArr.push(csv_parse(line,headers));
    });
    console.log(dataArr.length);
    if(dataArr.length == 3000){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArr));
      await timeout(6000);
      console.log("timeout");
      dataArr = [];
    }
  }
    reader.close(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

reader.nextline() stops working after line 370 even though the while loop is executing. however when I move the await outside of the if the code seems to work fine. Why is this happening.

Comment: Your function does not return a Promise in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing promises (`async/await`) with callbacks (`reader.nextLine()`), which is causing your problems.

Specifically, you're calling `reader.close()` too early, because it gets called before all lines have been read; the 370 lines that do get read is probably what fits into the buffer that gets read from the file before it gets closed.

A solution would be to also make reading the next line promise-based, for instance like this:

```
const getNextLine = async reader => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.nextLine(function(err, line) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(line);
    });
  });
}

lineReader.open(filename, async function(err, reader) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dataArr = [];
  while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    let line = await getNextLine(reader);
    dataArr.push(csv_parse(line, headers));
    console.log(dataArr.length);
    if (dataArr.length == 3000) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArr));
      await timeout(6000);
      console.log("timeout");
      dataArr = [];
    }
  }
  reader.close(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. But I'm still confused as to why the code ran when await timeout() was moved out of the if block. Also even though the reader.nextLine() stopped being called after the 370 or so tries, the while loop was still running(checked by logging at the start of the while). How did the code below the loop execute when while has not completed. Am I missing something here, like maybe the callback of reader.nextline() is nonblocking maybe?

Comment: @AshithR yes, that's another thing: `reader.nextLine()` isn't blocking at all. When you move the `await` outside the `if`, it will "block" (not really, it's asynchronous) until the timeout is reached, for every line that is read (also, not really, but close enough). So closing the reader will happen much closer to the point where all lines have actually been read.